# Javascript split string in different sized substrings

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, splice

I need to code an algo that, giving a hex string,generates an array with 5 elements of 4 hex digits and another array with 2 elemetents of 2 hex digits long. The unique two premises are:

- if the 4 digit string is = "0000" don't take it into account and if the 2 digit long hex is "00" (EDIT: or "01") don't take it into account neither.
- don't use the digits used for the five 4char strings for the 2char strings. I don't mind if one starts form the beginning and the other one from the end or the middle, or both from the middle...i mean the substrings don't need to be consecutive, they just have to be different from 0 and same string positions not used in both arrays. Edit: Imagine that the five 4char sequences are built using the first 20 characters (there is no "0000" sequence after splitting the main string every four chars). That means that the two 2char sequences don't have to take into account the first 20 chars as they have already been used.

Example of one correct output:

String : 87b86156d0000a4200005e02002f56614f7a2f54f7ebf45670ed62cbaa78e6f228297b0e7338215fb4

first array: ["87b8", "6156", "d000", "0a42", "5e02"]

second array: ["2f", "56"]

My approach starts like this:

```
var mystring = "87b86156d0970a4200005e02612f56614f7a2f54f7ebf45670ed62cbaa78e6f228297b0e7338215fb4"
var firststring = mystring.match(/.{1,4}/g);
```

Which gives me:

["87b8", "6156", "d097", "0a42", "0000", ...]

then:

```
for (x=0;x<firststring.length;x++){
        if (firststring[x]=="0000") {firststring.splice(x, 1)}
}

  var secondstring = mystring.match(/.{1,2}/g);
```

Which gives me:

["87", "b8", "61", "56", "d0", "97"...]

```
for (x=0;x<secondstring.length;x++){
        if (secondstring[x]=="00") {secondstring.splice(x, 1)}
}
```

Here is where i am lost, i don't know exactly how to code the part where i avoid the main string digits (positions) to be used in both arrays...

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's not pretty, but it works:

```
var str = "87b86156d0970a4200005e02612f56614f7a2f54f7ebf45670ed62cbaa78e6f228297b0e7338215fb4";

var grabLength = 4,
    // 4-char strings
    grp1 = [],
    // 2-char strings
    grp2 = [],
    chunk;

while(chunk = str.slice(0, grabLength)) {
  str = str.slice(grabLength);

  // skip all zeros
  if (/^0+$/.test(chunk)) continue;

  if (grabLength === 4) {
    if (grp1.push(chunk) === 5) {
      grabLength = 2;
    }
    continue;
  }

  // skip 2-char sequences that match the start of a 4-char sequence
  var hasMatch = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < grp1.length; i++) {
    if (chunk === grp1[i].slice(0, 2)) {
      hasMatch = true;
      continue;
    }
  }
  if (hasMatch) continue;

  grp2.push(chunk);

  if (grp2.length === 2) break;
}

console.log(grp1);
console.log(grp2);
```

**[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/legozodosadu/1/edit?js,console)**

Comment: great it works! I'm just curious about why it got "2f" as the first 2-digit-lenght string after the last 4-digit-length "5e02" instead of the next 2-digit-lenght substring that was "61"...

Comment: ok i see, as "61" is already part of the second 4-digit-lenght string it doesn't take it into account...in this case it should take it into account as the 61 is in different possition and should be valid for the first 2-digit-lenght string

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by position? I interpreted that as "the first two characters of any of the 4 character strings". Should it instead be "the first 2 character sequence shouldn't match the first two characters in the first 4 character sequence"?

Comment: Or, should a 2 character sequence be invalidated if it matches any 2 adjacent characters in the corresponding 4 character sequence?

Comment: Imagine that the five 4char sequences are built using the first 20 characters (there is no "0000" sequence after splitting the main string every four chars). That means that the two 2char sequences don't have to take into account the first 20 chars as they have already been used.

Comment: I don't know how to interpret this restriction: "don't use the digits used for the five 4-digit-lenght strings for the 2-digit-lenght strings.".

Comment: explained in my previous comment, i hope you understand me now, if not tell me, i will try to explain it another way. by the way thanks for your help man!

Comment: Given `["87b8", "6156", "d000", "0a42", "5e02"]`, is the `b8` in `["b8"], ["ff"]` allowable?  Or does is it only invalidated if it's the *first 2* characters in the corresponding sequence (e.g., `["87"], ["ff"]`)?

Comment: In your example: Given "87b86156d0000a425e0287b8" ["87b8", "6156", "d000", "0a42", "5e02"], ["87","b8"] PERFECT! Because the "87" and "b8" used for ["87","b8"] is different in the string than "87b8". Another example: Given "87b86156d0000a425e02ff01" ["87b8", "6156", "d000", "0a42", "5e02"], ["87","b8"] WRONG! There's no other "87" and "b8" in the string after the already used chars. In this case it should be ["ff","01"]

Comment: Ha, I'm getting very confused. I never used `["87", "b8"]` in my example.  (Although I realized I formatted it wrong; I intended to write `["b8", "ff"]`).  I just need to understand under what specific cases do we dismiss a 2-character sequence.  Can you please re-read my previous comment and answer my exact questions? Specifically, given `["87b8", "6156", "d000", "0a42", "5e02"]`, is 1) `["b8", "ff"]` correct? and 2) is `["87", "ff"]` correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63125/discussion-between-aitor-and-jmar777).